# Difference between unbalance load connected to grid vs isolated generator

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, electric-machine, synchronous

Given two cases as following-

**CASE 1**

An isolated 3-phase synchronous generator in star connected to a star-star 3-phase transformer and then secondary of transformer is connected to a highly unbalance load. Assume no neutral is present.

**CASE 2**

A grid is connected to a 3-phase star-star transformer and then to a highly unbalance load in similar manner as above.

What will be the difference between analysis of both cases?

1. I think in 2nd case we don't need to worry about grid voltages as it behaves like an ideal voltage source with constant impedence in series even though load is highly unbalanced, but I'm not sure whether we can use per phase analysis or not because of the presence of 3-phase  transformer. How can I approach this? (I only need a hint.)
2. While in first case it seems like we have to worry about the generator voltages also and transformer causes even more complexity, is there any particular method to analyse these types of cases?

Comment: The grid isn't an ideal voltage source, it has some impedance.

Comment: @Hearth , thanks ! edited.

Comment: @user215805, I recommend you to define better the transformer connection. Something like YNyn, or Yyn, or YYn, or Yy... I think it is important to model it...

Comment: Hi@Luiz Oliveira, I had already mentioned that transformer are in star -star (Y-Y) and neutral is not present anywhere.but if you can give some hint I'll appreciate it

Comment: Why can't we use symmetrical component analysis here? Draw the positive negative and zero sequence networks, find the respective seq voltages and currents, add them to obtain actual phase currents and voltages? we need to know the impedances though (I've just started learning power systems, I just want to join the discussion, I'm not sure if my statement makes sense)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BcMrRZ9 Like this?

Comment: @Aravindh Vasu  , if load connected to grid we can use symmetrical component analysis as you shown in figure, but problem started when there is an isolated generator because unbalanced load may cause unbalacing of generator as well and that's the main  problem